# React native IOS pushViewController error only on release build

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, expo

I have a react native project where I am trying to present a external view controller using React Native iOS Native Modules.

In my AppDelegate, I have instantiated a viewController using storyboard and populating it with  react `createRootViewWithBridge` view.

**AppDelegate.mm**

```objectivec
UIView *rootView = [self.reactDelegate createRootViewWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"main" initialProperties:nil];               
rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];                                                                                

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];                                                    
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];                                                

UIViewController *reactViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"ReactViewController"];           
reactViewController.view = rootView;                                                                                            

UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*)[storyboard 
                    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"UINavigationController"];       
[navController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
self.navController = navController;                                                                                             
self.window.rootViewController = navController;                                                                                 

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];                                                                                                       [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
return YES;
```

I have a IOS native module that I call using from my react Side:

**Homescreen.tsx**

```
SdkModule.openPendingAuthorization(                                                                                       
  RAS_USER_ID,                                                                                                                  
  RAS_CLIENT_ID,                                                                                                                
  RAS_CLIENT_SECRET,                                                                                                            
  RAS_URL                                                                                                                       
)
```

And then in my native module method, I am pushing the viewcontroller into the navigation controller.

**RCTSdkModule.m**

```objectivec
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(openPendingAuthorization:(NSString *)userId
                                  clientId:(NSString *)clientId
                                  clientSecret:(NSString *)clientSecret
                                  url:(NSString *)url)
{
  
    Data *obj=[Data getInstance];
    obj.userId = userId;
    obj.clientId = clientId;
    obj.clientSecret = clientSecret;
    obj.url = url;
  
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
      UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *) app.delegate.window.rootViewController;
      UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
      UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"SdkViewController"];
      [nav pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    });
}
```

And then, I am able to run the SDK code in viewcontroller related to SDK:

**SdkViewController.m**

```objectivec
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // SDK Related Code
}
```

My code runs fine when I run it as DEBUG build in XCode. But, if I switch to Release build or, Create ipa using `eas build`, it gives me the following error.

`unrecognized selector sent to instance-pushviewcontrolleranimated

It seems that, in `[nav pushViewController:viewController animated:YES]` , the `nav` is a viewController, not a UINavigationController. But it does not give the error in Debug mode.

Comment: How do you switch between DEBUG and RELEASE build? Do you have different TARGETS ?

Comment: @ThilinaChamathHewagama, I don't have multiple targets. Only two different build configration. https://imgpile.com/images/TyIYxc.png